# is there anyway to populate empty list of objects within the scope of Page_Load after page loading?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dropzone.js

the problem is that i want to populate `var docfiles = new List<string>();` with some files names uploaded by user using **dropzone js** but the list wont populate because for first time page loaded `httpRequest.Files.Count > 0` which means there's no file uploaded by user  is there any idea to fill the list after user upload file and for sure that will be after page load ?

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
    HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = httpRequest.Files;
    var docfiles = new List<string>();


    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < uploadFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadFiles[i];
            int fileSizeInBytes = postedFile.ContentLength;
            string fileName = postedFile.FileName;// Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            string fileExtension = "";

            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            string savedFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/items/");
            string filename = path + savedFileName;
            postedFile.SaveAs(filename);
            docfiles.Add(filename);
        }
        itm.img1 = "ASs";

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the IsPostBack property will tell you if this is an initial page load or the result of a post-back, so check it before checking for uploaded files.

[MSDN Docs on IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: @ajjawi Another poster edited my answer to add a code sample that was broken.  I have fixed it.  Try it now

Comment: I apologies for the wrong code, I just wanted to show the OP an example.